# How to keep this centered and aligned?

Tags: html, css

Currently I have two divs on the left and right of this body div, and I'm trying to place one in the center and at the same height as the others. I am able to center it between them but when I publish it and look at it, it's below or far above the other divs and won't stay at the same height as them. Any suggestions? I also removed a lot of features inside of the left div seeing as it wasn't necessary to keep the code shorter.

```css
#bod{
  background-color:darkred;
  height:500px;
  width:90%;
  margin:auto;
  border:3px solid black;
  border-radius:25px;
}

#left{
  background-color:tan;
  height:400px;
  width:155px;
  overflow:none;
  border-radius:15px;
  border:3px solid black;
  margin-left:7px;
  margin-top:50px;
  animation-name:Curver;
  animation-duration:4s;
  animation-iteration-count:infinite;
  animation-direction:alternate;
  float:left;
  margin-left:10px;
}
  

#cen{
  background-color:tan;
  width:455px;
  height:400px;
  border:3px solid black;
  border-radius:15px;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  margin-top:auto;
  margin-bottom:auto;
  position:absolute;
  border:3px solid black;
  border-radius:15px;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  top:0;
  float:left;
}


#right{
  background-color:tan;
  height:400px;
  width:155px;
  margin-top:50px;
  margin-right:7px;
  float:right;
  border-radius:15px;
  animation-name:Curver;
  animation-duration:4s;
  animation-iteration-count:infinite;
  animation-direction:alternate;
  border:3px solid black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title> Formal CSS Project </title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  
  <body>
    <div id="header">
      <div id="innerheader">
        <h1>
        Sample
        </h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <center> <ul id="nav">
      <li><a href="Exe.com">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="Exe.com">Photos</a></li>
      <li><a href="Exe.com">Statistics</a></li>
      <li><a href="Exe.com">Chat</a></li>
      <li><a href="Exe.com"> Biography </a></li>
      </ul>
    </center>
    <div id="bod">
      <div id="left">
        <h1>
          Our Goals
        </h1>
        <ul>
          <li> <a href="Exe.com">Achieve</a></li>
          <li> <a href="Exe.com">Be Amazing</a> </li>
          <li><a href="Exe.com">  Succeed </a> </li> 
          <li><a href="Exe.com">  Support </a> </li> 
        </ul>
        
        
      </div>
      
      <div id="cen">
      </div>
      
      <div id="right">
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `position: relative` to your `#bod` rule.

Answer (score 2):

**Please add position relative to parent div.**

```css
#bod{
  background-color:darkred;
  height:500px;
  width:90%;
  margin:auto;
  border:3px solid black;
  border-radius:25px;
  position: relative;
}

#left{
  background-color:tan;
  height:400px;
  width:155px;
  overflow:none;
  border-radius:15px;
  border:3px solid black;
  margin-left:7px;
  margin-top:50px;
  animation-name:Curver;
  animation-duration:4s;
  animation-iteration-count:infinite;
  animation-direction:alternate;
  float:left;
  margin-left:10px;
}
  

#cen{
  background-color:tan;
  width:455px;
  height:400px;
  border:3px solid black;
  border-radius:15px;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  margin-top:auto;
  margin-bottom:auto;
  position:absolute;
  border:3px solid black;
  border-radius:15px;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  top:0;
  float:left;
}


#right{
  background-color:tan;
  height:400px;
  width:155px;
  margin-top:50px;
  margin-right:7px;
  float:right;
  border-radius:15px;
  animation-name:Curver;
  animation-duration:4s;
  animation-iteration-count:infinite;
  animation-direction:alternate;
  border:3px solid black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title> Formal CSS Project </title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  
  <body>
    <div id="header">
      <div id="innerheader">
        <h1>
        Sample
        </h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <center> <ul id="nav">
      <li><a href="Exe.com">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="Exe.com">Photos</a></li>
      <li><a href="Exe.com">Statistics</a></li>
      <li><a href="Exe.com">Chat</a></li>
      <li><a href="Exe.com"> Biography </a></li>
      </ul>
    </center>
    <div id="bod">
      <div id="left">
        <h1>
          Our Goals
        </h1>
        <ul>
          <li> <a href="Exe.com">Achieve</a></li>
          <li> <a href="Exe.com">Be Amazing</a> </li>
          <li><a href="Exe.com">  Succeed </a> </li> 
          <li><a href="Exe.com">  Support </a> </li> 
        </ul>
        
        
      </div>
      
      <div id="cen">
      </div>
      
      <div id="right">
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
#cen{
 background-color:tan;
 width:455px;
 height:400px;
 border:3px solid black;
 border-radius:15px;
 margin-top:50px;;   
 border:3px solid black;
 border-radius:15px;  
 float:left;
 margin-left:200px; 
}
```

It will help you. Output:
[image]